# Tag synonym suggestion: world-war-2 -> ww2

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

There's a [world-war-2](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-2) with eight questions that should probably be made a synonym for [ww2](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ww2).  I'd suggest it myself but, as is usual for tag synonyms, I don't have the reputation or answer score required.

(And just for completeness, [world-war-ii](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-war-ii) as a synonym might be a good idea.)

Comment: Also WW1 tags; like  [tag:first-world-war] or  [tag:world-war-1] - I remember editing one of those into ww1 recently.